# Is it better to stream a single document or a whole collection from Firestore?

Tags: flutter, firebase, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions

I'm making an app that displays the current status of several APIs on the home screen and I was wondering if it would be more performative if I had all the API statuses on a single document that would get updated each time the cron job fires the API, and I would be streaming this single document.

Or is having each API be its own document in a separate collection and then streaming the collection to the home page to display the current status for each document not matter in terms of performance?

The number of APIs isn't huge, so the actual performance wouldn't be that much different either way, but I'm wondering in theory which would be better.

Comment: Nice question, Jack.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When it comes to Firestore, you'll always have to pay a number of read operations that are equal to the number of documents you actually read. So when it comes to costs, it's better a read a single document rather than multiple documents.

> The number of APIs isn't huge.

I'm not sure what "isn't huge" means, but if all the data from all APIs fit into a single document, then you can go ahead with that. But remember, there is an important limitation here. You can add data into a single document [up to 1 MiB](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/quotas#collections_documents_and_fields) of storage. If you want to be sure that you cannot reach the maximum size of a document, you can use a Firebase Extension called [Firestore Document Size](https://extensions.dev/extensions/alexmamo/firestore-document-size).

There is also a downside. When you nest all the data into a single document, you cannot query the data. You have to dig into the document data yourself. The best option that you have is to keep the data in two places. One document that contains all the data of all APIs and a collection that contains documents for each API separately. So if you need the data of all APIs read the document that contains all the data, if you need the data of a particular API, perform a query and read the data form the particular API. In both cases, you'll have to pay a single read.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! Now I'm wondering that when it comes to making a chat app that streams a messages collection to display the chats between two users. If you stream the entire collection to query based on the uids of the two users does the stream only read the chats created by the two users or does it read all the chats created by all users on the app?

Comment: If you apply filter, then you'll only read the documents that correspond to those users and nothing more.